# Взять текст между двумя скобками

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярных выражений изъять текст , который между двумя скобками?

```
Страниц: 320 (Офсет)
```

А мне нужно записать в строку слово **Офсет**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Изменено!**

Попробуйте вот такое:

```
.*?\(([^)]*).* - неправильный пример, сорри, не учитывается закрывающая скобка!
```

Нужно вот так:

```
.*?\(([^)]*)\).*
```

Тест на Руби:

```
mystring = 'Страниц: 320 (Офсет)'.match('.*?\(([^)]*)\).*')[1]
puts mystring
```

Запишет в переменную mystring значение 'Офсет'

http://ideone.com/54Rrsz