# Элементы внутри строк в скобках умножить на (-1)

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста как найти элементы начинающиеся на '(' и умножить их на (-1). Чтобы в новый список сохранились элементы положительные и отрицательные (со скобочками которые)
Исходное:

```
['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'плрстгарг']
```

Конечное:

```
[2342746, - 4836482, 7493332]
```

Мой код:

```
my = ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332'] 
def test(data: str):
   if num := ''.join(filter(str.startswith('('), data)):
        return int(num) * (-1)
   if num := ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, data)):
        return int(num)
    
test1 = list(map(test, my))
print(test1)
```

Я так понимаю что в первом if возвращается только индекс а не то что я хочу.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Взять текст между двумя скобками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600001/%d0%92%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=122294

Answer (score 2):

Не так красиво, зато спустя  годы понятно будет что хотели.

```
my = ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332']


def test(data: str):
    data = data.replace(" ", "")
    if data.startswith('('):
        return int(data.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")) * (-1)
    else:
        return int(data)


test1 = list(map(test, my))
print(test1)
```

Comment: Забыл добавить я в вопрос что там могут быть ещё '-', или текст любой. Затупил( ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'плрстгарг']

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

my = ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'плрстгарг']

def fmt(item: str):
           # Если после всех манипуляций в строке что-то осталось
           # Пытаемся привести значение к int
    return int(val) if (
        val := re.sub(
            # Все не цифры и не знак минус 
            # или знак минус за которым нет цифр, 
            # или знак минус который находится не в начале строки
            # меняем на пустую строку
            r'[^\d-]|-(?!\d)|(?<!^)-', '',
            re.sub(
                # Забираем в группу все, что находится между скобками            
                # (без самих скобок)
                # и возвращаем символы группы добавив знак `-` веперди
                # (если соответствующа условию строка не была найдена
                # вернет оригинал строки)
                r'\((.+)\)', r'-\1', item
            )
        )
     # Если получили пустую строку то возврашаем None
    ) else None

# применяем функцию к списку значение и убираем из результата None
test1 = list(filter(None, map(fmt, my)))
print(test1)
# [2342746, -4836482, 7493332]
```

Comment: Забыл добавить я в вопрос что там могут быть ещё '-', или текст любой. Затупил( ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'плрстгарг']

Comment: @BieKuf, обновил ответ

Comment: @BieKuf, не корректно обновил в первый раз. Сейчас попробуйте

Answer (score 1):

Однострочник, например:

```py
my = ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332']
print([-int(y[1:-1]) if y.startswith('(') else int(y) for y in (x.replace(' ', '') for x in my)])
```

Comment: Забыл добавить я в вопрос что там могут быть ещё '-', или текст любой. Затупил( ['2 342 746', '(4 836 482)', '7 493 332', '-', 'плрстгарг']